# Error backports install ath9k using 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, wireless, ath9k

make clean
make
Below Error after make install command  (kernel ver. 3.8.0.33-generic)

Let me know what the problem.

```
root@msis1:/home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1# make install

  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 36 modules

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/compat/compat.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/compat/cordic.k

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/compat/crc8.ko

Can't read private key


  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/compat/sch_codel.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/compat/sch_fq_codel.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/media/common
/cypress_firmware.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/media/media.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/media/parport/bw-qcam.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/media/parport/c-qcam.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/media/parport/pms.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/media/parport/w9966.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/media/v4l2-core/v4l2-
common.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/media/v4l2-core/v4l2-dv-timings.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/media/v4l2-core/videobuf2-core.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/media/v4l2-core/videobuf2-memops.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/media/v4l2-core/videobuf2-vmalloc.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/media/v4l2-core/videodev.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/atl1c/atl1c.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/atl1e
/atl1e.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/atlx/atl1.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/atlx/atl2.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath5k/ath5k.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath6kl/ath6kl_core.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath6kl/ath6kl_sdio.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath6kl/ath6kl_usb.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_htc.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/carl9170/carl9170.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/net/wireless/libertas_tf/libertas_tf.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/drivers/net/wireless/mac80211_hwsim.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko

Can't read private key

  INSTALL /home/msis_park/Downloads/backports-3.12-1/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko

Can't read private key

  DEPMOD  3.8.0-33-generic

depmod will prefer updates/ over kernel/ -- OK!

Note:
You may or may not need to update your initramfs, you should if
any of the modules installed are part of your initramfs. To add
support for your distribution to do this automatically send a
patch against "update-initramfs.sh". If your distribution does not
require this send a patch with the '/usr/bin/lsb_release -i -s'
("Ubuntu") tag for your distribution to avoid this warning.

Your backported driver modules should be installed now.
Reboot.
```

Answer (score 1):

'Can't read private key' may safely be ignored. The ending message was not 'abort' but, instead, 'Your backported driver modules should be installed now. Reboot.' I suggest you do so. Then check that the correct module is being used:

```
modinfo ath9k
```

The version should be:

```
version:        backported from Linux (v3.12-0-g5e01dc7) using backports v3.12-1-0-g9ae6b6c
```

And your wireless should be working as expected.

Comment: Thank you for answer but ath9k don't work wireless card

After reboot modprobe ath9k Error : insert modul : not directory or file

I don't konw why this problem what is the cause of message? (can't read private problem) (ex : compatible kernel ver. or other problem)

Comment: That's a completely different question, isn't it? I suggest you start a new question and tell us about your device (lspci -nn) and your kernel version (uname -r). Perhaps ath9k is not correct for your device.