# Install Huion h580 tablet driver from source code

Tags: graphics-tablet

I have a Huion h580 tablet, that I bought from dx.com and it doesn't work at ubuntu.
I found this driver: https://github.com/DIGImend/huion-driver
It should be installed from the source code, but what I did didn't work:

```
paulo@paulo-mccartney:~/Downloads/huion-driver-master$ make
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/paulo/Downloads/huion-driver-master modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic'
CC [M] /home/paulo/Downloads/huion-driver-master/hid-huion.o
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 1 modules
CC /home/paulo/Downloads/huion-driver-master/hid-huion.mod.o
LD [M] /home/paulo/Downloads/huion-driver-master/hid-huion.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic'
paulo@paulo-mccartney:~/Downloads/huion-driver-master$ cd /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24

paulo@paulo-mccartney:~/Downloads/huion-driver-master$ sudo make install
[sudo] password for paulo:
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/paulo/Downloads/huion-driver-master modules_install
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic'
INSTALL /home/paulo/Downloads/huion-driver-master/hid-huion.ko
Can't read private key
DEPMOD 3.13.0-24-generic
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic'
install -D -m 0644 hid-huion.conf /etc/depmod.d/hid-huion.conf
depmod -a
install hid-rebind /sbin
install -m 0644 hid-rebind.rules /lib/udev/rules.d/70-hid-rebind.rules
udevadm control --reload


paulo@paulo-mccartney:~/Downloads/huion-driver-master$ rmmod hid-huion
rmmod: ERROR: Module hid_huion is not currently loaded
```

Also found this video which installed this tablet in Debian:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJ0-N0GMeXw
But I don't know how to compile the kernel to support the tablet.

How could I install this driver?
Thanks

Comment: "Cant read private key" may be discarded, http://askubuntu.com/questions/379714/error-backports-install-ath9k-using-12-04-lts

Comment: Since module is not loaded at the first place, why would you unload it ? compiling a module doesnt load the module automatically

Comment: To install the driver you just compiled, do `insmod hid-huion.ko` as root in the directory where you have that .ko file

Comment: Thanks. I loaded but keep not working... :/

Comment: what is the `dmesg` output after loading the driver ?

Comment: did you found a solution ?

Comment: Yes. Actually My driver was loading correctly. Just make install did it. The problem was my model of tablet which was not supported by the driver but [I contacted the developer and he fixed](https://github.com/DIGImend/huion-driver/issues/4').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DIGImend](http://digimend.github.io/) released a new driver at https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers . You can also use `modprobe hid-huion` to force it to load, that may help you. Your commenter is correct about examining dmesg output for more information.

Comment: Actually, I had contact the developer at github and he released a new driver for my model. Thanks